# Replace part of input value on keypress jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example I have, input type with predefined length.
I want to achieve, when the input value is bigger or equal to 3, to replace that part of string[3] with '/';

```
<input type="text" id="number" maxlength="6" placeholder="MM/YY"/>
```

And here is jquery

```
$('#number').on('keypress',function(){
if(this.value.length <= 3) {
this.value.replace(this.value[3],'/');  
}
});
```

So in short when user types inside input field for example: 1234, the number 3 needs to be replaced with '/' and than the value would be 12/2017, like expiration date of credit card. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this. Had to change the maximum length of input's value from 6 to 7.

Try with e.g. 12/2017.

```js
$('#number').on('keypress', function() {
  if (this.value.length >= 2) {
    this.value = this.value.slice(0, 2) + '/' + this.value.slice(3, this.value.length)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="number" maxlength="7" placeholder="MM/YY" />
```

Comment: Awesome Thanks :)

Comment: One small issue is that if a user types "12/", they end up with "12//".  It might be good to test the value for "/" before doing the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following.

Where delimeterIndeces is where in the string you want to check and change the values. InputString is the string returned from the input tag.

```js
let delimeterIndices = [2,5]; // "02[/]15[/]2017";
let inputString = "123152017";
let resultString = inputString.split('').map((char, index) => {
  if(delimeterIndices.indexOf(index) !== -1) {
    return '/';
  } else {
    return char;
  }
}).join('');

console.log(resultString);
```